# IntelliJ WAR Artifact missing folders after synchronising gradle

Tags: typescript, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a Spring MVC application that includes typescript. The typescript is transpiled via a gradle task from the folder `src/main/ts` to `build/ts`

Then the resulting JavaScript files are included in the WAR file via

```
war {
    into("typescript") {
        from typescript.outputs
    }
}
```

When I do a synchronization between gradle and IntelliJ it creates an artifact that looks like:

[image: IntelliJ WAR Artifact]

The `typescript` is missing in there.

If I do a synchronization between gradle and IntelliJ after I ran the `typescript` gradle task it creates an artifact that looks like:

[image: IntelliJ WAR Artifact after running task]

What could I do to get the folder in the artifact from the beginning? Should I file a bug against IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue. You can use the [workaround suggested in this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158556#focus=Comments-27-3779156.0-0):

> you may try this Gradle plugin:
> https://github.com/jetbrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin It can be used to
> configure Idea artifacts:
> https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin/wiki/DSL-spec-v.-0.3
> But you will have to duplicate settings in `war` and
> `idea.project.settings.ideArtifacts` sections

Comment: thanks for your answer, I had a quick look into that workaround and it is pretty difficult to recreate the structure of the WAR artifact manually via the plugin, will have to decide if it is worth it